# use-package gnus ignores :bind

Tags: key-bindings, gnus, use-package

In my emacs config i wrote:

```
    (use-package gnus
      :bind (("<f12>" . gnus)
         :map gnus-group-mode-map
         ("q" . gnus-group-suspend)
         ("Q" . gnus-group-exit))
    :config ........)
```

After i load emacs, f12 works, but "q" and "Q" do not work in gnus buffer. Only when i manually load the same code these keys work.

Could you help me to automatically bound these keys?

Comment: I bind keys if i add in :config section: (with-eval-after-load "gnus-group"
    (bind-key "q" #'gnus-group-suspend gnus-group-mode-map)
    (bind-key "Q" #'gnus-group-exit  gnus-group-mode-map))
  ). Is it possible to make it more pleasant with use-package?

Comment: `(use-package gnus-group ...)`?

Comment: This is John Wiegley's config for gnus: https://github.com/jwiegley/dot-emacs/blob/master/dot-gnus.el . Try adapting his code.

He uses that `(use-package gnus-group ...)` and `bind-key`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when use-package is evaluated the gnus-group-mode-map has no value so the key binding is not made.

Refer to https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/503

The following might work (but you lose the deferred loading)

```
(use-package gnus
  :init
     (require 'gnus)
  :bind (("<f12>" . gnus)
     :map gnus-group-mode-map
     ("q" . gnus-group-suspend)
     ("Q" . gnus-group-exit)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyword `:map` needs to be inside parenthesis. You can have multiple :bind keywords, so it is clearer to separate keys bound to separate modes. This should work:

```
(use-package gnus
  :bind (("<f12>" . gnus))
  :bind (:map gnus-group-mode-map
              ("q" . gnus-group-suspend)
              ("Q" . gnus-group-exit))
  :config ........)
```

I did not tried this code but it is based on my functioning elfeed config.

Comment: This does not work. According to use-package tutorial one can write like this :bind (("M-s O" . moccur)
         :map isearch-mode-map
         ("M-o" . isearch-moccur)
         ("M-O" . isearch-moccur-all))

Comment: There might be something that you are missing in how gnus works. 

`use-package` is a macro and you can use a package called `macro-step` to explore the generated lisp code https://github.com/joddie/macrostep .  Copy and eval the generated code.